# How can I see the exit code of a program running in the PowerShell console

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I really need to check out the numerical value of a command that I run in Windows PowerShell.

The `$?` only returns True or False, but I need the actual error number.

Is that possible? In linux is just `echo $?` but Windows makes it difficult!

```
PS C:\work\> copy

Cmdlet Copy-Item an der Befehlspipelineposition 1
Geben Sie Werte für die folgenden Parameter an:
Path[0]:
PS C:\work\> echo $?
False
PS C:\work\>
```

And while you are here, what would be the solution for normal command prompt?

Comment: Powershell is just different from what you are used to, and one of the things it doesn't guarantee is return codes. Powershell is an Object-orriented shell, so instead of returning primitives like an integer, it will generally return an object, of which the integer might be a member, depending on type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the exit code of the last Win32 executable that ran at `$LastExitCode`.

However, you did not run a Win32 executable but the `Copy-Item` cmdlet. It does not have an exit code.